# Fallback language when translation does not exist

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, multilingual

I have a working multi-language site (joomla core support).

My question is, in the case of having an untranslated, for example, an article, is it possible to fallback to the one in the default language? The only way I am thinking to achieve it is to duplicate the untranslated article until the translation will be done.

Appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicating untranslated articles is a good option.
Also, you can set the language of untranslated articles to "All", until you have a translation, then set the correct language for each translation.

**Update**
After Joomla 3.9 has been released, duplication can be done using the Propagate button which has been added according to the [pull request for Issue #21250](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/21321)